# What can a democratic government do that an autocrat cannot?

Tags: democracy, taxes, dictatorship

I mean to ask are there any actions that an autocrat wouldn't have the ability to do but a democrat(small d) would. For instance prohibition, conscription or a hike in the tax rate. Things that would lead to revolutionary attitudes in the subjects of an autocratic state but would go down fine with citizens in a democracy.

Comment: The wide majority of democratic leaders can **retire** and live their old days peacefully in their own country. That's something that very few autocrats can enjoy: they either stay in power until their death, or go into exile, or face trials, or get jailed or killed by new powers, or are attacked and sometimes lynched by angry mobs.

Comment: @Evargalo However, this is not always the case, see Gorbachev, for example.

Comment: Policing by consent?

Comment: @AJFaraday: I've a few doubts that African Americans were being policed the way they were by consent in Ferguson and elsewhere.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I never made that claim, I'd go as far as to say that what you've just accused me of saying is categorically and provably untrue.

Comment: @AJFaraday: Oh, I'm sorry if that passed off as accusatory. It was not at all the intent, and I apologize if you took it that way. What I meant was that democracies are so that policing is by consent _of the majority_, rather than by the population as a whole - with unfortunate side effects for minorities in the US (or in many places in Europe, for that matter).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy It's a complicated term, all told. I dare say that there'll never be a system in which nobody will resist law enforcement, for instance. However, the system known as 'policing by consent' hasn't, to my knowledge, been implemented in a non-democratic society.

Comment: @AJFaraday: Agreed it's complex and not easy, but I'd respectfully put forward that it actually has been done in the past. Among other time periods, policing by consent occurred during the French Revolution (which degenerated into the Reign of Terror), in the 2nd French Republic (which turned into the 2nd French Empire) and in the Weimar Republic (which became the 3rd Reich). In each case consent extended well into the switch to an autocratic regime - until the very end or until it was too late to matter.

Comment: There are many examples of democratic countries introducing prohibition or tax hikes, including by referendum (Norway, Iceland).  Your premise is flawed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are, but what exactly those things are will depend on the specific political context the autocrat and democratic government find themselves in.

### The Theory

A government of any kind is constrained to a certain set of actions. They may be constrained by formal institutions (laws, branches of government, specific scopes of operation) or informal things (political competition, conflict, agreement or disagreement between factions).

Democratic governments typically have formal constraints in the form of a constitution. It constraints what the state can and cannot do. Additionally, democratic leaders must be re-elected. So they are effectively constrained by what the electorate will support.

Autocratic leaders have a similar problem. Although they are not similarly constrained by laws or institutions, they are constrained by a group of people they must please. These will typically be key ally-groups in certain industries, regions, or political positions.  Maintaining their support is important, because without them the autocracy will fall apart.

How do the two compare? The democratic leader has a relatively wide set of options, because there are many potential groups within the electorate that they could satisfy and still be re-elected. Effectively they have a "menu" of potential winning strategies to pick from. The autocratic leader has a small menu because they have only a few key groups. This means they are far more constrained than the democratic leader.

### The Specifics

Unfortunately, the specific policies that are possible will depend on the political context of the autocratic regime and the democratic regime that you select for comparison.

---

*The "authoritative" text on this is "Transitions from Authoritarian Rule". It's a four-part series of books that lays this all out in great detail.*

Comment: That's interesting! Your point about the menu of potential winning strategies was what I was unable to articulate.  A top tier tax rate of 94%, like in 1944 USA for example, would be unlikely in an autocracy since autocrats usually rely on elite support was an example I was thinking of. Your theoretical explanation is far better though

Comment: It's perhaps counterintuitive, but democratic governments can claim they have a "mandate" from the people to do something.  Many _de_ _facto_ autocracies therefore dress themselves up in democratic clothing so that they can pretend to have the blessing of the people.  A _de_ _jure_ autocracy can't get away with that claim, and might be constrained by the threat of revolt.

Answer (score 10):

They can take criticism.

A autocrat must guard their power; any dissent is a potential threat of revolt. Autocrats generally have at most a small class of supporter trusted enough to make suggestions.

The hoped virtue of democracy is that all bugs are shallow with enough eyes, when the government screws up someone will say so and if it is true people and therefore government will correct it. An autocrat has to vet all information to determine if his enemies are laying sneaky traps, and since his enemies cannot compete directly they will.

Mao [tried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Flowers_Campaign) to prove this wrong and no one liked the results.

Answer (score 3):

A general principle of most Democratic governments is that government is by the people and for the people, so there are typically restrictions placed on the government that limit it's power from the start (in the form of a Constitution.  The UK and New Zealand are the only Representative Democracies that lack Constitutions.  Australia has a constitution in the form of multiple documents and not one single document).

Thus most modern democracies are limited from day one in their ability to do everything an autocrat can do, as the nature of by the people and for the people must protect the people's ability to abolish a government that is no longer meeting their needs (usually by voting out the bums, but there are other issues at play).  This is seen as a limitation on the leaderships authority to rule.

Now that isn't to say that there are democracies with autocratic rule.  Saddam Hussain once bragged that he had gotten 100% of the vote for his re-election, something George Bush never got... of course the vote asked "Do you want Saddam Hussain to be President? Yes or No."  And if you circled "No" you were arrested... but those aren't considered democratic for the purposes of this conversation.

To frame this to question, Democratic Governments are able to be peacefully rejected in favor of a Government that can better fit the needs of rejection, which prevents violent uprising of the people in Autocratic states if the same changes are desired.

Comment: This seems to answer what an autocracy can do that democracies cannot. OP asked whether there are things a democracy _can_ do that autocracies cannot.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy:  Basically the long version is not a damn thing.  Basically, the question is what can be done in a democracy that would result in revolt in an autocracy, which is basically the changing of who holds the powers of government.

Comment: The first paragraph is not entirely accurate: (1) [Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Laws_of_Israel) and [Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Canada) also don't have formal constitutions. (2) Although it's true that Australia has a number of documents of constitutional significance, one of those documents is a [Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Australia). [See also here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncodified_constitution).

Comment: @hszmv There are many counterexamples where changes in powers in government of autocracies did not entail uprisings. In fact, most older authocracies manage this quite smoothly, be it China, North Korea, or (for most of the time) the former Soviet Union. Only few transitions lead to uprisings, and mostly uprisings occur against elderly leaders that fail to secure their power and seem so weak that a revolt might be successful (e.g. Ben Ali, Mubarak, Mugabe etc.).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff:  But those two documents are still considered constitutional.  U.S. Constitutional Law also use the works of the framers of the Constitution to determine what they had in mind when making the law.  Separation of Church and State does not come from the Constitution but from Federalist Papers explaining the meaning behind the First Amendment and reasoning for the barriers.  My use of the word constitution was merely as a document that confined the powers of a government.

Comment: @Nebr:  The fact that a (violent) revolution against the government has not happened does not mean it cannot... however, autocracies have little recourse to vent tensions that could lead to such incidents by the people.  I also don't look at successful uprisings so much as bloody messes of internal politics.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, democratic leaders elevate the interests and well being of their people while autocrats don't, largely because democratic governments are accountable to the people, while autocrats are not. If democratic governments do not respond to the will of the people... they get voted out. Good motivation to keep the people's interests in mind.

Best example of this would be N Korea vs S Korea. Same people, same geography, same resources... which citizen lives better? By an incredibly wide margin?

We have the first world right next door to the third world, with the only real difference being the form of leadership.

Comment: Communists are the second world, developed and developing are better terms for what you mean. Also people like Mao or Hitler seem to have sincerely aimed to elevate their people, and achieved some successes at some times, the problems were their views on what "elevate" and "their people" meant.

Comment: Hitler may have had a desire to elevate racial purity, but Germany was far worse off for having him as a leader. As for Mao, his main interest appeared to be in controlling the people and securing his position. Hence the massacres in the 'cultural revolution', which improved no one's life but Mao's.

Comment: in general, this might be true, but Korea is a wrong example! both "nations" have been shaped by autocratic leaders, it just happened they followed completely different ideologies (communism vs free market (anticommunism?)). democracy in S Korea is quite recent phenomenon, the booming economy was built before that.